# Replacing segments of MPEG DASH video

Tags: xml, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg-dash

I am working with a converted DASH video with a manifest file containing a segmentList of all video segments. Is it possible to take multiple of these segments, encode an image overlay (using ffmpeg for example) and change the manifest file to correspond to the converted video segments combined with the original ones (those following the converted ones) without re-encoding the entire original video with the image overlays and then converting it to DASH?

Comment: Hey @Mike, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is yes - this is more or less what two stage forensic watermarking solutions do, although the image they insert is invisible usually.

The Streaming Video Alliance have released a document describing at a high level the technique in their doudment 'SVA-Watermarking_FINAL_071918.pdf'. It is available at the time of writing at this link:

- https://www.streamingvideoalliance.org/download/27623/

The video has some or all of the segments copied so that a segment embedded with an 'A' and a segment embedded with a'B' marker exists for that segment. The client then selects either an A or B segment, depending on playlist manipulation for example, and the users viewing experience is the same wither they see either the A or the B segment.

This is a concrete example of being able to manipulate or update a segment within an ABR stream and still have the video playback as the user expects. In fact, the ability to be able to play back a different bit rate version of a segment is another example of the ability to have individual segments be manipulated separately without affecting the rest of the playback, but the watermarking may be easier to relate to your specific requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what tools would you recommend to achieve this? Is it possible to have also a visible watermark within the video without having an instance of each of those videos and just use those changed parts in the original video, please? If so what tools would you recommend, please?

Comment: Inserting the image into the video like this is not something that you will find ready tools for I think. If it works for you, it would be easier to insert the image into the section of the video you want, using ffmpeg before you segment and deliver the video. Alternatively you could add an overlay via a separate stream - see an example here: https://www.unified-streaming.com/blog/how-make-your-media-streams-smarter-using-timed-metadata

Comment: Unfortunately inserting a SCTE-35 marker is not an option for us. We are trying to secure videos using personalized banners that are within the video, however we cannot keep a personalized video for each user since that would take a significant amount of storage. What would be your suggestion to inserting a banner to a part of the video and just inserting those parts into the stream, please? I have already tried manually rewriting timestamps and other values in the video to match the original, however this didn't work either since timestamps and many other values differed.